# jQuery selector for elements with name attribute

Tags: jquery

How can I select elements which contains "name" attribute ?

Example of the elements :

```
<select id="itemPK.country.id_id" name="itemPK.country.id"><option value="7">India</option><option value="8">Malaysia</option></select>

<input id="point_id" name="point" type="number" value="">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('[name]')
```

try this you can get all elements having name

Answer (score 2):

The [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) are what you need:

```
$('input[name="point"]')...
$('[name="something"]') //In case it's not specifically an <input> element
```

Good luck

Edit: I see, you may have asked for elements which contain a certain attribute, not those that contain X value in the name attribute. The answer provided by PSR is the way to go. [This](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) is the documentation for the "Has attribute" selector.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$("*[name='point']")
```